# split a value into values in max, min range

Tags: python-3.x, math, mathematical-optimization

I want to find an efficient algorithm to divide an integer number to some value in a max, min range. There should be as less values as possible.

For example:
max = 7, min = 3
then

```
8 = 4 + 4
9 = 4 + 5
16 = 5 + 5 + 6 (not 4 + 4 + 4 + 4)
```

**EDIT**

To make it more clear, let take an example. Assume that you have a bunch of apples and you want to pack them into baskets. Each basket can contain 3 to 7 apples, and you want the number of baskets to be used is as small as possible.

** I mentioned that the value should be evenly divided, but that's not so important. I am more concerned about less number of baskets.

Comment: How do you define "evenly divided"? What makes "16=5+5+6" a better solution than "16=4+4+4+4"?

Comment: sorry that I didn't make it clear, I've updated the question, thanks

Comment: Ok, next question: What exactly makes "16=5+5+6" better than "16=6+6+4"?

Comment: both are acceptable in this case, so there may be more than one way to divide the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This struck me as a fun problem so I had a go at hacking out a quick solution. I think this might be an interesting starting point, it'll either give you a valid solution with as few numbers as possible, or with numbers as similar to each other as possible, all within the bounds of the range defined by the min_bound and max_bound
    number = int(input("Number: "))
    min_bound = 3
    max_bound = 7

```
def improve(solution):
    solution = list(reversed(solution))
    for i, num in enumerate(solution):
        if i >= 2:
            average = sum(solution[:i]) / i
            if average.is_integer():
                for x in range(i):
                    solution[x] = int(average)
                break
    return solution

def find_numbers(number, division, common_number):
    extra_number = number - common_number * division
    numbers_in_solution = [common_number] * division
    if extra_number < min_bound and \
    extra_number + common_number <= max_bound:
        numbers_in_solution[-1] += extra_number
    elif extra_number < min_bound or extra_number > max_bound:
        return None
    else:
        numbers_in_solution.append(extra_number)
    solution = improve(numbers_in_solution)
    return solution

def tst(number):
    try:
        solution = None
        for division in range(number//max_bound, number//min_bound + 1):  # Reverse the order of this for numbers as close in value to each other as possible.
            if round (number / division) in range(min_bound, max_bound + 1):
                solution = find_numbers(number, division, round(number / division))
            elif (number // division) in range(min_bound, max_bound + 1):  # Rarely required but catches edge cases
                solution = find_numbers(number, division, number // division)
            if solution:
                print(sum(solution), solution)
                break
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("Solution is 1, your input is less than the max_bound")

tst(number)
for x in range(1,100):
    tst(x)
```

This code is just to demonstrate an idea, I'm sure it could be tweaked for better performance.

Comment: With the short solution, you could probably iterate through the list to see if there was an average that'd bring the numbers closer together. For example, if your solution was [5, 5, 5, 2] it would first look at 5 and 2, their average is 3.5, so it would skip it. Then it would look at 5, 5, 2, their average is 4, so it can update the solution to [5, 4, 4, 4].

Comment: if input is 20 then the result is [5, 5, 5 ,5]. It should be [7, 7, 6]

Comment: Not anymore! I've updated it above. It needed to check rounded division before floor division. I added in the averaging idea to, so it'll try to take those answers like [5 ,5 ,5, 2] and turn them into [5, 4, 4, 4]